# Exchange 2013, flow messages to a third-party smtp

Tags: exchange, smtp, archive, journalling

I plan to use a SMTP Archiving feature in my archiving solution (non Microsoft). I wish to send a BCC copy of every message to a particular SMTP server (installed on archiving software). In Exchange 2003 there was a BCC journaling feature that could be enabled in a registry. Is  there any way to direct all messages, external and internal, to a third-party SMTP server on Exchange 2013/2016? On that separate SMTP server I have an archiving software that can capture and archive incomming messages. I'm not able to use standard Exchange Journaling, since I have no licenses to integrate my currect archiving solution (non Microsoft) with a Journal Mailbox.

Any ideas? How to configure it in Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using transport rules that are applied to messages.
add a new transport rule that adds an additional recipient (bcc).

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you. Now I am wondering about something else. My archiving server is a separate SMTP server (not only a recipient). How to make Exchange to send the message both, to MBX server and to Archive Server. Shoud it be a separate (sub)domain with additional MX records in DNS?

Comment: How about Shadow redundancy? [link] https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351027(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: in my understanding shadow redundancy is just intended to have a temp copy of a mail to reduce chances of losing a mail after having it accepted via smtp.
to provide a transparent mechanism in between you may setup a smarthost on sending that offers message duplication - which is in general much more complicated than using the bcc copy (if this is sufficent for your needs)

Comment: No need to add additional DNS records etc.
Setup a specific Send Connector for the sub domain. So archive.example.com. Then configure the Send Connector to use a smart host and enter the IP address/DNS name of the other server. 

Although why not just configure journaling within Exchange and have the address set correctly? No need to BCC, that is what journaling is designed to do.

Comment: I can configure journaling in Exchange, but I thought that Journal Reports need to be send only to an Exchange Mailobx (not any entered e-mail address). Can I enter ANY e-mail address for Journal Reports? Even from another domain or subdomain?

Comment: Finely I used Database Journaling, poited it external contact and send connector to direct messages to a specified SMTP host.